# In TypeScript, should I give the datatype to the variable if I know?

Tags: typescript

`let isDone = true;` is the right way OR `let isDone: boolean = true;` is the right way? What should we use in TypeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either is fine. One is just more explicit.

Generally, i would recommend adding type annotation in cases where the result type is *not* obvious. More importantly, turn on `strict` in the compiler options and you will be forced to add annotations in the places that really matter (implicit `any` cases, for example).

Having such redundant type annotations actually has one slight benefit besides additional readability without compiler support: If you later edit the value, you cannot accidentally assign the wrong type without noticing it.

e.g.

```
// Change it to false
let isDone: boolean = 'false'; // Errors
```